# Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:+

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, google-plus-signin

Trying to integrate login with google plus in my ionic project using the cordova-plugin-googleplus plugin by EddyVerbruggen. Without the plugin installed the project builds fine but once I install the plugin building fails and I get this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
  >   Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:+.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/maven-metadata.xml
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/maven-metadata.xml
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix this. You need to have the following installed in your Android SDK manager (Under the 'Extras' folder):

- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library
- Google Play services
- Google Repository

I installed them and it worked for me.

[image]

josschne's comment on this link https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/77 tipped me in the direction of checking to see whether I had them installed, In my case I did not.

Comment: Im facing the above issue , I got an answer by you but im struck with how to add the Android Support Repo and Android Support Lib ? Could you please Help Me man ??

Comment: Assuming you extracted the sdk contents you downloaded in your home folder, navigate to tools using this command `cd ~/android-sdk-linux/tools` then do `./android`. An interface similar to the picture I posted in my answer above will appear, scroll down to extras and check Android Support Repo and Android Support Lib then click install.

Comment: first of all thanks @Axel Ingadi , and Im a windows user so just `cd ~/android-sdks` then I did `android` , i got an window which u have posted  like above , yeah..,

Comment: You also need the Google Repository

Answer (score 0):

As an update to the above answer, this is the configuration that you want as of December 2016.

[image]

The Android Support Library is now obsolete, but by having the Android Support Repository, Google Play services, and Google Repository installed I am able to build successfully. I don't think that Google USB Driver is required.

Another tip is if you have Android Studio and Cordova Tools for Visual Studio I recommend pointing them both to the same sdk, as Visual Studio installed the sdk again when I installed my Cordova Tools.

Hope that helps!